# Data analysis with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, data-analysis

Today my data analysis routine would be something like the following: do the heavy work with either R, Julia or Python and then display it in the web with JavaScript (for example, using D3.js).

My initial focus with JS was mainly data visualization/interaction with the end product of the analysis, so I started studying it with this in mind. But I was wondering: are there JS libraries focused on data analysis (data manipulation with the notion of data frames, implementation of statistical models) so it would be feasible to do some of the heavy work directly in JavaScript?

Comment: Yes. Javascript is much more efficient than you think, if you use it correctly.

Comment: @bjb568 Those libraries you linked are for data visualization.

Comment: Oh, whoops. http://okfnlabs.org/recline/ and https://github.com/wayoutmind/gauss

Comment: I'm working on a JavaScript data analysis library. I'm keen to get feedback if you want to try it. https://www.npmjs.com/package/data-forge

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I can list a number of projects that can help you in this process:

1. d3js, which you already mentioned. It is not only limited to visualizing but also looking at the [API](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/API-Reference) section of the library, offers many manipulation methods.
2. [DataSet](https://github.com/misoproject/dataset/) offers a good way to manipulate data.
3. [TableTop](https://github.com/jsoma/tabletop) is a library intended for parsing of CSV data
4. [jStat](https://github.com/jstat/jstat) is a library for statistical data analysis.
5. With a bit of googling I also found this interesting website, full of infos: https://jgoodall.me/2012/02/01/javascript-statistical-libraries

Comment: Also consider http://learnjsdata.com

Comment: For someone with good SQL background, [SQL Frames](https://sqlframes.com) is a good JavaScript library for creating and manipulating DataFrames within the browser.